# Get headers feign netflix

Tags: java, web-services, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

I'm using [netflix feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) to communicate microservices.

So my Microservice A has an operation 'OperationA' which is consumed by the Microservice B and it passes one param by header named X-Total to B

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
 headers.add("X-Total", page.getTotalSize());
```

My client interface is as next:

```
@Headers({
    "Content-Type: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
})
@RequestLine("GET Dto/")
List<Dto> search();

static DtoClient connect() {
    return Feign.builder()
        .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
        .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
        .target(ConditionTypeClient.class, Urls.SERVICE_URL.toString());
}
```

Then I've get the list of dto, but I don't know how to get the header X-TOTAL param:

```
public List<Dto> search() {
    DtoClient client = DtoClient.connect();
    return client.search();
}
```

How do I get the header params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Custom decoder

You could use a custom decoder:

```java
public class CustomDecoder extends GsonDecoder {

    private Map<String, Collection<String>> headers;

    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
        headers = response.headers();
        return super.decode(response, type);
    }

    public Map<String, Collection<String>> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }
}
```

#### Return Response

Other solution could be return Response instead of `List<Dto>`:

```
@Headers({
    "Content-Type: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
})
@RequestLine("GET Dto/")
Response search();
```

Then deserialize body and get headers:

```
Response response = Client.search();
response.headers();
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(response.body().asReader(), Dto.class);
```

Comment: I've used your previous suggestions: change  my search() method to return Response and then get headers and parse body. It works fine!! This Idea It's good as well,

Comment: @PauChorro I ended up deleting that comment. But both approaches should work :)

Comment: For the first option (Custom decoder), how then can getHeaders() method of the decoder be accessed from code using the feign client?

Comment: How to handle if response is void (204 - NO_CONTENT) ? It does not go to decoder at all

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting late to the party, but I know for someone in the future it could help

We can wrap our `response` into a `ResponseEntity<SomePojo>`, by doing that we can access as the **headers** object as the **body** with type `SomePojo`.

```
...
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
...


public ResponseEntity<List<Dto>> search() {
    DtoClient client = DtoClient.connect();
    return client.search();
}
```

Comment: This is easier than using a custom decoder